# RayCast in unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm trying to use a raycast in unity that only reflect off of an objects i define but it didn't work with me any help please?
my game is laser reflection so it's not like a shooting game i need the laser to be visible the whole time and i only Need the laser to be reflected off of the mirrors and not the walls, not the floor nor the other objects in the room.
i tried this code.

```
public class RaycastReflection : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int gunDamage = 1;
    public float hitForce = 1f;
    private Transform goTransform;
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    private Ray ray;
    private RaycastHit hit;
    private Vector3 inDirection;
    public int nReflections = 2;
    private int nPoints;

    void Awake()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {      
        nReflections = Mathf.Clamp(nReflections, 1, nReflections);
        ray = new Ray(goTransform.position, goTransform.forward);
        nPoints = nReflections;

        lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(nPoints);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, goTransform.position);

        for (int i = 0; i <= nReflections; i++)
        {
            //If the ray hasn't reflected yet  
            if (i == 0)
            {
                //cast the ray 100 units at the specified direction  
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, out hit, 100))
                {  
                    inDirection = Vector3.Reflect(ray.direction, hit.normal);
                    ray = new Ray(hit.point, inDirection);

                    if (nReflections == 1)
                    {
                        lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(++nPoints);
                    }

                    lineRenderer.SetPosition(i + 1, hit.point);
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, out hit, 100))
                {
                    Target health = hit.collider.GetComponent<Target>()
                    if (health != null)

                    health.Damage(gunDamage);

                    if (hit.rigidbody != null)
                        hit.rigidbody.AddForce(-hit.normal * hitForce);

                    inDirection = Vector3.Reflect(inDirection, hit.normal);
                    ray = new Ray(hit.point, inDirection);

                    lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(++nPoints);
                    lineRenderer.SetPosition(i + 1, hit.point);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you've tried to code an attempt already - great! When you tried it, what happened? What worked, what didn't? How does the code perform differently from how you want? This is all useful information to readers of the question, and should be edited into the question body.

Comment: You aren't checking anything about the result of the Raycast. You are just indiscriminately reflecting it off the first object hit and "damaging" the second.

Comment: I'll provide a better answer when I get a few but what I would do is setup on the hit, another if statement, something like if hit.gameObject.tag == "reflectable" then create another ray from the hit.point. Then you can get the angles from Vector3.Reflect like you are.

Comment: `Mathf.Clamp(nReflections, 1, nReflections);` is redundant. `nReflections` will always be within the bounds of 1 and itself. (Assuming `nReflections` is always positive. If it's negative or 0, the method could potentially throw an error.)